# Joining the correct budget date range fields based on the date of a service

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have two tables I need to join. The first  table contains the date a service was given and the cost of that service. The second table includes the maximum budgets for a service for a given period of time. The service below has two budgets, one which starts '4/2/2012' and ends '4/2/2013’ but is renewed the same day it ends on ‘4/2/2014’.   The service was administered 4/15/2013 
So, I would need to attach the budget which is relevant to the time of the service:'4/2/2013' to '4/2/2014'.  Since one budget ends in April and is renewed in April   In the program below both budgets are joined.

**I need to join the start_date and end_date where DOSSTART falls between the two dates.**

```
CREATE TABLE #Service_Budget(
        ID int,
        SERV_Type int,
        Start_DT  datetime,
        End_DT  datetime,
        Budget int, 
        NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_OF_SERVICES int
    );
INSERT INTO #Service_Budget VALUES 
(13946, 5,  '4/2/2012', '4/2/2013', 622.4, 12), 
(13946, 5,  '4/2/2013', '4/2/2014', 788.4, 12) 

CREATE TABLE #Service_Visits(
ID  int,
Service_Type int,   
DOSStart datetime,
BillableUnits int,
RATE_AMOUNT int
 );

INSERT INTO #Service_Visits VALUES
(13946, 5,  '4/15/2013', 3,75.5)


SELECT    
a.ID,
a.Service_Type,
a.DOSStart,
MONTH(a.DOSStart) AS Month,
YEAR(a.DOSStart) AS Year,
MONTH(b.START_DT) AS Start_Month,
YEAR(b.START_DT) AS Start_Year,
b.Start_DT,
b.End_DT,
 a.RATE_AMOUNT,
 (a.RATE_AMOUNT * a.BillableUnits) as Total,  
 b.Budget,
 b.NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_OF_SERVICES
 FROM #Service_Visits as a join #Service_Budget as  b
   on a.ID=b.ID
```

This is what I get:

```
ID  Service_Type    DOSStart    Month   Year    Start_Month Start_Year  Start_DT    End_DT  RATE_AMOUNT Total   Budget  NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_OF_SERVICES
13946   5   2013-04-15 00:00:00.000 4   2013    4   2012    2012-04-02 00:00:00.000 2013-04-02 00:00:00.000 75  225 622 12
13946   5   2013-04-15 00:00:00.000 4   2013    4   2013    2013-04-02 00:00:00.000 2014-04-02 00:00:00.000 75  225 788 12
```

Notice both budgets are joined, note the budget that is relevant to DOSSTART date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `BETWEEN` clause `on a.ID=b.ID AND DOSStart BETWEEN Start_DT AND End_DT` . try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Service_Budget(
        ID int,
        SERV_Type int,
        Start_DT  datetime,
        End_DT  datetime,
        Budget int, 
        NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_OF_SERVICES int
    );
INSERT INTO #Service_Budget VALUES 
(13946, 5,  '4/2/2012', '4/2/2013', 622.4, 12), 
(13946, 5,  '4/2/2013', '4/2/2014', 788.4, 12) 

CREATE TABLE #Service_Visits(
ID  int,
Service_Type int,   
DOSStart datetime,
BillableUnits int,
RATE_AMOUNT int
 );

INSERT INTO #Service_Visits VALUES
(13946, 5,  '4/15/2013', 3,75.5)


SELECT    
a.ID,
a.Service_Type,
a.DOSStart,
MONTH(a.DOSStart) AS Month,
YEAR(a.DOSStart) AS Year,
MONTH(b.START_DT) AS Start_Month,
YEAR(b.START_DT) AS Start_Year,
b.Start_DT,
b.End_DT,
 a.RATE_AMOUNT,
 (a.RATE_AMOUNT * a.BillableUnits) as Total,  
 b.Budget,
 b.NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_OF_SERVICES
 FROM #Service_Visits as a join #Service_Budget as  b
   on a.ID=b.ID AND DOSStart BETWEEN Start_DT AND End_DT
```